# Serialport writeline textbox error

Tags: c#

I use virtual COM ports for testing my program. I want to Serial Write with COM8 and Serial read with COM9. When a want to write the values from textbox1, i get this error:

```
IOException was unhandled (The parameter is incorrect)
```

How do i get rid of this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace Flowerpod_User_Interface
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            // show list of valid COM ports
            foreach (string s in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(s);
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);


            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("SerialPort1 is not open");
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

                serialPort1.Open();

                textBox3.Text = "Open"; 
            }

        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random slumpGenerator = new Random();
            // Or whatever limits you want... Next() returns a double
            int tal = slumpGenerator.Next(1000, 10000);
            textBox1.Text = tal.ToString();
        }

        private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }




     private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!serialPortRead.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = "COM9";

                serialPortRead.Open();

                textBox4.Text = serialPortRead.ReadLine();                 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the Message of the unhandled IOException?

Comment: The driver is unhappy about something.  Not setting any of the serial communication settings, like baudrate and databits, etc.  Maybe.

Comment: The message of the unhandled error is: The parameter is incorrect

Comment: I have made COM8 and COM9 a virtual com port pair, and both ports have the standart baud rate "9600" Stop Bits "1" etc. I use COM8 for serial Write and COM9 for serial Read.

Comment: @user2292615 you must set the speed/parity/stopbits etc for the port in C# before you open it.  It doesn't matter what the ports are set for anywhere else, the framework needs to know. Also, what line is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There wasn't any bridge between the two ports which caused the problem. The virtual COM port software tricked me !.