# Serial Port write Timeout error

Tags: c#

When i try serial write to a COM port, this error occures. Does the virtual COM port cause this problem ?. I use a bridge between two virtual COM ports, one for serial write and the other one for serial read.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace Flowerpod_User_Interface
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            // show list of valid COM ports
            foreach (string s in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(s);
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);


            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("SerialPort1 is not open");
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

                serialPort1.Open();

                textBox3.Text = "Open"; 
            }

        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random slumpGenerator = new Random();
            // Or whatever limits you want... Next() returns a double
            int tal = slumpGenerator.Next(1000, 10000);
            textBox1.Text = tal.ToString();
        }

        private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }




        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!serialPortRead.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = "COM11";

                serialPortRead.Open();

                textBox4.Text = serialPortRead.ReadLine();                 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is: TimeoutException was unhandled: The write timed out

Comment: Does this error always occur? Or are you able to write sometimes?

Comment: Is this related to or an expansion of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070651/serialport-writeline-textbox-error?  If the answer is yes to either, please update the original question, don't ask more than once.

Comment: Yes but when i made the bridge between COM8 and COM9, It gives a TimeOut error in the same line now when i Serial Write, instead of the IOException error.

Comment: Hi Jim. The error always occures, and i can't write anything.